# ReactJS: Move component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a dialog-heavy application. Often, a component needs to launch a dialog in a fire-and-forget fashion, so I have a function `create_dialog()` that takes a `React.DOM` element and appends it to the `dialogs` array in the state of the `App` component (the top-level component) which in its `render()` function renders all dialogs.

This is easy to use and works fine, but now I want to be able to minimize dialogs and show a little preview in a task bar. The way I tried to do this is to add a new array `previews` to the `App`s state and when minimizing a dialog, I would remove it from `dialogs` and append it to `previews` which is rendered into a different element on the page.

The problem is that `React.DOM.*` elements are just lightweight references that don't store state, so when minimizing dialogs all state is lost because the dialog components have to be remounted (and as far as I know there is no way to really move a DOM element in ReactJS).
Is there an easy way to move/copy the state of a component without making changes to it?
Or is there a different approach?

```
var Application = React.createClass(
{
    getInitialState: function()
    {
        return {dialogs: [], previews: []};
    },

    render: function()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="previews">{this.state.previews}</div>
                {this.state.dialogs}
            </div>
        );
    },
    ...
});

var g_app = React.renderComponent(<Application />, ...);

function create_dialog(header, content)
{
    var new_dialog_state = g_app.state.dialogs.slice();
    new_dialog_state.push(<Dialog header={header}>{content}</Dialog>);
    g_app.setState({dialogs: new_dialog_state});
}

var Item = React.createClass(
{
    onButtonClick: function()
    {
        create_dialog('Item info', <ItemInfo data={this.state.item_info} />);
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: you probably need to hide them instead of removing them from dom, see [stateful children](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#stateful-children). and also, it seems not quite right of the way how you use the "state"

Comment: But even if I were hiding instead of removing them I would still need their state. And yeah, I don't like putting DOM elements in the state either, it was just the first solution that came to my mind.

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem by storing the state outside components. Components now only user their `props` which are set by a separate `Store` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

> Okay, I solved the problem by storing the state outside components. Components now only user their props which are set by a separate Store object.
>   [<sub>- DaviD.</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3491462/david)